# Make shapes without sides?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I am fairly new to Photoshop. I want to make an octagon without the top side and put a straight line through the top. So imagine a power symbol but shaped like an octagon. I tried using the pen tool to make the octagon, but it looked very crooked.

I then tried making a shape layer and adding an octagon, rasterized the layer so that I could edit it, and then rubbed the top side out bit it still looks a bit weird. I think there must be a easier way to do this. I do have access to other programs like Illustrator but would like to see if it is possible in Photoshop first.

I have put a screenshot in to show you what I am attempting to do.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks for your time and help! I really do appreciate it.

Comment: sooooo....what did you try? Give us something to show you worked on it a bit...This is a 2 shapes, 2 colors and 2 clicks job (literally) so, you get why I'm asking what have you tried.

Comment: @alin I tried using the pen to make the octagon, but it looked very crooked. I then tried making a shape layer and adding an octagon, rasterized the layer and then rubbed it out. I thought there must be an easier way to do it. Are you able to give some advise?

Comment: A rough screenshot would help us to visualize what you are trying to achieve. It's not that clear from your description.

Comment: @Selrond just did. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is easiest to achieve within Illustrator. Do you have access to it?

Comment: @Selrond I do but prefer to see if it is possible in Photoshop first as that is what I am used to using. I will, however, try using Illustrator if possible. Thanks for your prompt replies.

Comment: Making an octagon is pretty much as simple in Photoshop, as it is in Illustrator... kind of. `Polygon tool` exists in both applications. It's just that the way you want to orient the octagon is easier to do in Illustrator. Illustrator always creates it with one side of the polygon at the bottom (if you create it by clicking once or by holding shift, while clicking and dragging), where as Photoshop doesn't. In PS you have to eyeball it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click Polygon
2. On top of Screen set to 8 sides, choose a stroke, and leave fill empty:

[image]

3. Draw your shape
4. Use the Direct Select to tap the Top Line, hit Delete

[image]